# Why is ReflectionParameter::isArray always returning false?

Tags: php, oop, reflection

So I have this simple code:

```
<?php

class TestClass {

    public function test_function($id, $values = array()) 
    {
        
        $ref_met = new ReflectionMethod(__METHOD__);
        foreach($ref_met->getParameters() as $param) {
            if($param->isArray()) {
                echo "$param->name is an array\n";
            } else {
                echo "$param->name is NOT an array\n";
            }
        }       
    }

}

$t = new TestClass();
$t->test_function(5, array());
```

The `$values` method argument is an array, you can tell in the function definition, however, if I use reflection to get the method parameters information they always return as not being an array.

I can try even extracting the reflection relevant code to another separate function so that It does not execute on the method itself, but to no avail:

```
<?php

class TestClass {

    public function test_function($id, $values = array()) 
    {
                
    }

}

function test_reflection() 
{
    $ref_met = new ReflectionMethod('TestClass::test_function');
    foreach($ref_met->getParameters() as $param) {
        if($param->isArray()) {
            echo "$param->name is an array\n";
        } else {
            echo "$param->name is NOT an array\n";
        }
    }
}


test_reflection();
```

Is there something I'm not understanding about reflection on PHP? I've read and re-read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.isarray.php) but I can't find anything that tells me I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using PHP 5.4.20, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because RelectionParameter::isArray() checks if the method expects if the parameter is an array.  Not if the method is defaulted to be an array.  It is examining for the type hint not the default parameter.  Without the hint, the parameter can be anything so the `isArray` check will be false.  The value is just defaulted to an empty array if nothing is provided for the parameter but as your signature is right now it could be anything.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.isarray.php

> TRUE if an array is expected, FALSE otherwise.

Make your class like this and it will be true:

```
class TestClass {

    public function test_function($id, array $values = array()) 
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: A newcomer thing I guess, did not know that you could hint types to arguments. Is this only possible with arrays or can you actually do it with any type?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php  You can type hint objects, interfaces, arrays or callbacks (as callable).